# 1[t] appears in mathematica expression

Tags: replacement

I am trying to do some symbolic manipulations on a function with huge amount of terms. Specially I use rules to substitute a particular kind of term with something else. In this course I found out that that expression 1[t] appears. 
I tried to evaluate it or plot the function to see what it is, but nothing happens. 
I will be glad if you can help me.

Regards

Comment: `foo=5; (*long procedure where you forgot that foo was used before*) foo[t]` so either it is a problem like that or some definitions from previous calculation are hanging around, quit the kernel.

Comment: Please read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18562) for more details on what Kuba is describing.